# extends Fragment Class variables, are not working

Tags: android, listview, nullpointerexception, fragment

im currently following a tutorial for implement a search bar to filter my listView, and my class goes like this:

```
package com.example.fragmenttabhostdemo;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class Tab1 extends Fragment {

    private ListView lv;
    private EditText et;
    private String listview_array[] = { "ONE", "TWO", "THREE", "FOUR", "FIVE",
            "SIX", "SEVEN", "EIGHT", "NINE", "TEN" };
    private ArrayList<String> array_sort= new ArrayList<String>();
    int textlength=0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

         //lv = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.ListView01);
        //et = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.EditText01);
        //lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listview_array));
     }
```

The problemas is, as soon as i delete the coments ("//") in the last lines, the apps doesn´t works... it says:

```
06-11 12:06:37.964: D/AndroidRuntime(3101): Shutting down VM
06-11 12:06:37.964: W/dalvikvm(3101): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb1a17ba8)
06-11 12:06:37.984: E/AndroidRuntime(3101): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-11 12:06:37.984: E/AndroidRuntime(3101): Process: com.example.fragmenttabhostdemo, PID: 3101
06-11 12:06:37.984: E/AndroidRuntime(3101): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-11 12:06:37.984: E/AndroidRuntime(3101):     at com.example.fragmenttabhostdemo.Tab1.onCreateView(Tab1.java:34)
```

i just think that is a problem using the variables, but, this... or change the privacity from private to public, have not worked.

i've started to learn android java, a week ago, so i'm really noob.

ty

P.S.  the return is missing cause there are a lot of code bellow the comments, but i omitted just to keep it simple. (sorry)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're never actually setting the view for the `Fragment`.  You can't call `getView()` inside of the `onCreateView()` method.  Instead, you should do the following.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, 
    ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // This is where you actually get your view.  
    // Replace R.layout.fragment_layout with the layout file you are using 
    View myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false);

    // Now you can call findViewById on your newly inflated view
    lv = (ListView) myView.findViewById(R.id.ListView01);
    et = (EditText) myView.findViewById(R.id.EditText01);
    lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listview_array));

    // Be sure to return the view!
    return myView;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Check this method:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 }
```

The return type of this method is View. Here you should inflate proper xml layout. So change it to this:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment,container,false);
//this is how you use findviewbyid inside fragment
Button myBut = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonMyBut);
return view;
 }
```